# Can views displayed as regions access parent controls?

Tags: c#, silverlight, regions

I have a view (parent) that is loading another view (child) as a region. I need to reference a storyboard that is located in the parent view from the child view code behind. Is this possible and how would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just make the storyboard a resource and make it available wherever for wherever you need it, especially if it's going to get re-used anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to:

First: in your parent view (View1) xaml, give a name of your child view like this:

```
<my:View2 x:Name="MyView2" />
```

2nd: in your view2.xaml.cs, add property like this:

```
public View1 MyView1 {get;set;}
```

3rd: in your view1.xaml.cs, set the property of step 2 in your constructor:

```
View2 v = MyView2 as View2;
   if (v != null)
        v.MyView1 = this;
```